# How to access all results from Php loop in an if statement

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

I am trying to figure out why I can only access last result from a loop. I have looked at many post on here and I can only find where OPs are asking how to create the loop

If I have a table named shirts and a column named colors
In the colors column the entiries are:

```
red
blue
green
```

and in my php page:

```
$user = new User();
$userid = $user->data()->id;

 $choices = array();
   if ($colorResults = $db->query("SELECT * FROM shirts WHERE sellerId = $userid")){
     if($colorResults->num_rows){
           while($row = $colorResults->fetch_object()){
                $choices[] = $row;
           }
           $colorResults->free();
      }
 }

foreach($choices as $choice){
   if($choice->color == 'red'){
       echo 'Yes color is red'
   } else {
      echo 'No color';
      }
}
```

When i display results

```
Results:
red
blue 
green
```

Heres the problem

```
if($choice->color == 'green'){
  echo 'Yes color is green'
} else {
   echo 'No color';
}
```

This will output successfully

```
Yes color is green
```

but if I change the code to:

```
if($choice->color == 'red'){
   echo 'Yes color is red'
} else {
   echo 'No color';
}
```

This result output will echo

```
No color
```

If one of the colors is red why will the if statement only see the last result
and how can I access all results to make the if statement true.

Comment: var_dump($choices->color);and take a look at it's output..

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see where you set `$choices->color`

Comment: I'm with @esqew here. It doesn't seem this is the entirety of your code, `$choices` should be an array. Mind posting the whole thing?

Comment: sorry forget to add the foreach loop.. I added it... really -2 down votes already its only been 2 min

Comment: So, where is the `if($choices->color == 'green'){` and `if($choices->color == 'red'){` in relation to the loop?

Comment: and is it actually `if($choice->color == 'red'){`?

Comment: Moreover, isn't `$choices` an array (evidenced by `$choices[]` directive)? How are you accessing an array with the `->` operator?

Comment: why are you using $choices in the foreach loop when you're defining foreach($choices as $choice), you should use $choice

Comment: When you check for `red`, simply echo the value to see why the color is not red. `echo $choice->color; echo 'No color';`. Then you can see why the check for `red` failed and take it from there. You might have a whitespace character in your database for that value.

Comment: @Don'tPanic the if statements are added in the forloop.

Comment: @N.B.  I have about 12 colors in that table I only used 3 in this posted question. I have adjusted the colors around in different orders, but my problem is, the if statement is only true with the last result and it does not recognize any of the other results

Comment: @Naruto when I var_dump $choice->color I get...  string(3) "red" string(4) "blue" string(5) "green"

Comment: After reading the answer which did what you needed to do - might I ask why is it important to check for existence of that color using PHP? It appears as the job for the database since they are queried and you can easily query whether there's a particular color based on `sellerId`. Even though you sorted your initial problem, it might be the best to settle it at the root - data model and determining what is what and if it exists on database level. The reason I'm writing this is because you can easily end up with less code - and in turn, less hassle.

Comment: @N.B. I used colors as example. Easier to explain and understand for others. My db is about times. A forloop to get $blocks of time in 30 min increments up to 24hrs, an if statement to remove all $blocks, except times thru a techs $open and $close, another if statement to remove $blocks of all confirmed clients appointments between $startTime and $finishTime. Basically an appointment script. But when I asked like this I was hassled for it. My problem was I was only accessing the last result from my foreach $startTime and $finishTime. I needed each result to be compared for potential removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think part of the initial confusion is that `$choices` is an array of objects, not an object itself, so using `if ($choices->color == 'red')` will get you a

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

which you may not see depending on your error reporting setting. But at any rate, if you use `if ($choices->color == 'anything')` you will always get 'No color.' So I assume that if it matches for green then you must actually be using `if ($choice->color == 'green/red/whatever')` and the other thing is just a typo.

The part where you have it listing all the colors of all the choices is fine (or at least, it was fine when you originally added it before subsequent edits.)

```
foreach ($choices as $choice) {
   echo $choice->color . '<br>';
}
```

What it *sounds like* is happening based on the results you are seeing is that you are checking the value of `$choice->color` after the foreach loop. `$choice` will remain set after the foreach loop, but it will always be the last value in the loop. Now, I am not sure exactly what you are going for here, but it looks like you want to list all the colors returned by your query and then check if a particular one is included. You could do that like this:

```
$color_included = false; // The color you're looking for has not yet been found

foreach($choices as $choice) {
    echo $choice->color . '<br>'; // List all the colors from your query
    // Check if they are the one you are looking for
    if ($choice->color == 'red') $color_included = true;
}
// Print the result
echo ($color_included) ? 'Yes color is red' : 'No color';
```

Comment: after 9 forums, reformatting the question 12 different ways, 18 downvotes, 7 days of trying, a stackoverflow suspension alert, It took you and your patients to understand. Yes that is what I was trying to accomplish and I implemented for what I needed and it works like a charm. I truly thank you. Thank you for restoring my view of stackoverflow. Now I want to truly understand it. I understand the rest of the code but why set color_included to false first?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. It is not exactly required, but the way I have it written, if the color you are looking for is not found during the loop, `$color_included` will never be set, and when you try to use it after the loop you will get a `Notice: Undefined variable:`. Initializing it to false avoids that.

Comment: ahhh OK! Great! thank you again, for you patience and understanding. Amazing how many will down talk and down vote rather than answering. Need more on here like you